# Github peer not authenticated when I issue g8 command

Tags: scala, github, sbt, typesafe-stack, giter8

I am using red hat linux. I am trying to run  this command:

`g8 typesafehub/play-scala`

And I am getting this response:

> Exception fetching from github peer not authenticated

But when I check the connection using

```
openssl s_client -connect github.com:443
```

I get this:

> Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Which means that I am able to connect with github. Why doesn't this command work?

`g8 typesafehub/play-scala`

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this issue on an `RHEL 5` VM image where I am using `openjdk 6`.  It was the other note to look at `TrustManager` clued me in on a fix.  I tweak the invocation to add a trust setting for github; in my situation it resolves the peer authentication issue.

First grab the github certificate using `openssl` and `keytool` to make it accessible to java.

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -connect www.github.com:443 \
    -showcerts 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -out github.cert
keytool -import -alias github \ 
    -file github.cert -storepass g8g8g8 \
    -keystore $HOME/g8.truststore
```

Now to rewrite the invocation with a script I call "G8":

```
g8 \
   \ -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$HOME/g8.truststore \
   \ -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=g8g8g8 \
   $*
```

Now try executing `G8 -v typesafehub/akka-scala-sbt` and I see things are much happier now.  I imagine setting a systemwide default truststore would may be better but I haven't figured that one out yet.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is an authentication issue, check your `~/.g8/config` file for [authentication purpose](https://github.com/n8han/giter8#private-repositories), but you shouldn't need it for anonymous access.

Note that, according to [issue 32 of giter8](https://github.com/n8han/giter8/issues/32), it can also depends on the Java you are using.
For instance:

> Sorry, that preview release of openjdk 7 is not fit for general use. (There's also giter8 issue #27 specific to openjdk on mac.) I have tested openjdk 7~b147-2.0-0ubuntu0.11.10.1 with giter8 and that worked fine, so when there is a final release available for mac you should be able to use it.
>
> **For now, please try with jdk 6** and reopen if you are still having trouble.

Another JDK (openjdk) might end up using the wrong `TrustManager`, as described in "[Avoiding the "`javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`" with `HttpClient`](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.fr/2010/07/avoiding-peer-not-authenticated-with.html)"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as B Evans (thanks for this!), but in Windows, so here is the equivalent code in case someone else has this issue and doesn't know how to do it from windows cmd. I also had to get openssl from http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

```
openssl s_client -connect www.github.com:443 -showcerts > out.txt
openssl x509 -out github.cert < out.txt
keytool -import -alias github -file github.cert \
 -storepass g8g8g8 -keystore C:\tmp\g8.truststore
```

Then add the same to JAVA_OPTS (I also had to deal with our corporate firewall and hence proxy as well...)

```
SET JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=our.proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 \
 -Dhttps.proxyHost=our.proxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\tmp\g8.truststore \ 
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=g8g8g8
```